# IText large pictures

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am writing program to generate PDF from pictures. I want to my pictures will be in normal size foreach page.For example i have image 2000px width and 10000px height and I don`t want to scalling this image. I want his natural size in PDF and not constant A3, A4 or A0. How can I solved that?
Thanks for helps.

Comment: What is the natural size of your px?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the dpi it's just a matter of creating a page with the correct size.

For example with 300dpi and 2000px the size would be (2000/300)*72=480.